# How to efficiently change delimiter in a csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file. The current delimiter is `,` . I want to physically substitute all commas to `|` .

Of course by ALL commas I mean those commas that work as delimiters. For example a comma inside the double quotes `"some text, text"` is not a delimiter and should not be substituted to `|`

Basically this is a very simple task to do with `Excel` is the file is small. But if it is large , then ?  What is the most efficient way ?

---

I could use openCSV API however, reading line by line is too slow (my dataset is huge)

Or I could use a Buffered reader which is also slow because it reads line by line .

Is there any more efficient way to convert a `,` delimiter file into `|` file ?

---

(PS : I have a code that i did not post here . it basically reads line by line . i even tried multithreading , but still my 50,000,000 rows get converted in an hour which is shamefully slow )

Comment: If you use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter in Java you should get close to disk speed.   Otherwise use native tools - for Linux `awk` or `perl` are good choices.

Comment: Did you try to profile your code? Maybe there is a trivial bottleneck somewhere.

Comment: If it is truly _a_ file, where "a" means "one", who cares about efficiency?  Even if the file is huge you only have to do it once.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that could speed it up is to mmap the file, which probably means rewriting in C or C++. But I agree with @AdamArold that you should profile to see where your program is taking time.

Comment: Reading line by line you should get about 90 MB/second and 50 million rows should take about a minute. The problem is likely to be your processing of the line.  BTW You can read the raw bytes and change those even faster.  Obvious CSV is not the most efficient way to store large datasets so you can't expect it to be fast.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

You are asking about a very specific *solution* and not mentioning the actual problem with a single word.

Ask yourself two questions:

1.) **WHY** is the CSV having a wrong delimiter? Can you change that during generation?

2.) **WHY** does YOUR Application require the CSV File to have a *certain* delimiter, rather than letting the user define the delimiter used in the file?

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1. Write your own CSV parser
2. Use an existing CSV library

For (1), if all the record in the dataset are 1 line each, then you can read them using the `readLine()` method of the `BufferedReader` class and for each record (line) you can read/write character-by-character, making sure not to replace the escaped separators (e.g., commas within quotes). If the dataset has complicated special cases like multiline records or other types of escaped characters (e.g., `'\,'`), don't even try (1) and follow the best approach, which in all cases is (2).

A CSV library (chose one that preserves spaces among fields, like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)) will allow you to read all records very fast (in the order of tens or hundreds of thousands of records per second, depending on how many fields a record has) and extract all the fields, which you will then need to rewrite to disk by joining them into records, separated by the new delimiter.

The whole task should not need 1 hour. It should be doable in around 15'.